# Django 2.2 ORM Exclude Not Working as expected

Tags: django, django-queryset

Im trying to get all customer list form `Cust` models that not having a record in Stat (ForeignKey), Django 2.2

```
class Cust(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Stat(models.Model):
    cust = models.ForeignKey(Cust, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

im trying this but doestn work,

```
    month = datetime.now()
    month = month.strftime("%Y-%m")
    
    inner_qs = Stat.objects.filter(date__icontains=month)
    data = Cust.objects.exclude(id__in=inner_qs)
    
    print(inner_qs)
    print(data)
```

The query above returning:

```
<QuerySet [<Stat: Ruth>]>
<QuerySet [<Cust: Jhonny>, <Cust: Rony>, <Cust: Sinta>, <Cust: Ruth>]>
```

As you can see, i need the result `[<Stat: Ruth>]` excluded from the data queryset/list.

but what i expected is:

```
<QuerySet [<Stat: Ruth>]>
<QuerySet [<Cust: Jhonny>, <Cust: Rony>, <Cust: Sinta>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to django doc [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) about `__in`, it states:

> In a given iterable; often a list, tuple, or queryset. It’s not a common use case, but strings (being iterables) are accepted.

There are several ways to solve this problem.

replace

```
    inner_qs = Stat.objects.filter(date__icontains=month)
    data = Cust.objects.exclude(id__in=inner_qs)
```

**1.** with

```
    inner_qs = Stat.objects.filter(date__icontains=month)
    data = Cust.objects.exclude(id__in=[o.cust_id for o in inner_qs])
```

**2.** Another way is to replace with

```
    id_list =Stat.objects.filter(date__icontains=month)\
            .values_list('cust_id', flat=True)\ 
            # flat=True will return list rather 
            # than tuple in the ValueListQueryset

    data = Cust.objects.exclude(id__in=id_list)
```

Here, you first generate an exclude id_list then use it to exclude.

**3.** a revised way of #2 with `distinct()`

```
    id_list =Stat.objects.filter(date__icontains=month)\
            .values_list('cust_id', flat=True)\
            .distinct().order_by() 
            # distinct() is used to get unique 'cust_id's
            # distinct() does not work without order_by()

    data = Cust.objects.exclude(id__in=id_list)
```

Comment: Thanks! its working! i only need to change ```id``` to ```cust_id``` in the solution given to make it work@

Comment: oops!!! I missed that part. I edited my answer and add distinct() method.